# xserver not using hotplug keyboard and mouse

Tags: x11, xorg, input, xinput

I'm using a Linux desktop. My own customized distro, using debian packages, but no `systemd` stuff.

The problem is if I re-plug the USB keyboard or mouse, the X will not respond to them anymore. unless I kill `xinit` process then `startx` again.

Also if I plug a second keyboard or mouse, them will not be used automatically by X.

More information, the `/dev` is handled correctly. Because `dbus-daemon --system` and `/lib/systemd/systemd-udevd` are in the `ps` list. And `evtest` will work correctly on the hot-plug/re-plug mouse or keyboard.

So I think the problem is laying on the part of how the X using these input devices as it's input.

My question is  what software or module doing the absent work?

Any workaround automatically or manually to adding `/dev/input/event*` to be used by X is acceptable.

Thank you.

Comment: Have you tried `xinput` tool? https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.5/doc/man/man1/xinput.1.html

Comment: Yes, i found `xinput --enable <device-id>` do the job.

Comment: So, you've fixed the issue, right?

Comment: Yes, I think so